# Problematic derivative.

Tags: derivatives

According to Gradshteyn, Ryzhik (2.323)

$$
\int P_m(x)e^{ax}dx = \frac {e^{ax}}{a}\sum_{k=0}^m \frac{(-1)^{k}P^{(k)}(x)}{a^{k}}  $$
where $P_m(x)$ is a polynomial in x of degree m and $P^{(k)}(x)$ is the k-th derivative of $P_m(x)$ with respect to $x$.

I am trying to evaluate the following:

$$ \int e^{-Rx}(1+Ae^{-k(x-b)})^{-1/A}dx \tag{a}$$

So according to 2.323 formula:
$$ \int e^{-Rx}(1+Ae^{-k(x-b)})^{-1/A}dx=\frac{e^{-Rx}}{-R}\sum_{n=0}^m \frac{(-1)^{n}\frac{d^{(k)}}{dx}(1+Ae^{-k(x-b)})^{-1/A}}{(-R)^{n}} $$

The problem I am facing is that even though I am slightly able to evaluate $\frac{d^{(k)}}{dx}(1+Ae^{-k(x-b)})^{-1/A}$ but I can't match my result with that obtained from Wolfram Alpha:

$$\frac{-e^{-Rx} }{R} \cdot {}_2F_1(\frac{1}{A},\frac{R}{k},\frac{k + R}{k}, -A e^{-k(x-b)})$$

No matter how many times I derivate the term $\frac{d^{(k)}}{dx}(1+Ae^{-k(x-b)})^{-1/A}$ the term $(1+Ae^{-k(x-b)})^{-1/A}$ stays in the answer forever. In contrast it is completely absent from Wolfram Alpha's result.

I tried to solve the integral by hand using integration by parts and I got:
$$
 \int e^{-Rx}(1+Ae^{-k(x-b)})^{-1/A}dx = \color{red}[\frac{e^{-Rx}}{R} (1+Ae^{-k(x-b)})^{-1/A}\color{red}{]}
\\ \cdot \color{red}{\big[}1-(-1/A)(1+Ae^{-k(x-b)})^{-1}\frac{(-Ae^{-k(x-b)})}{\frac{R+k}{k}}
\\ + (\frac1A)(1+\frac1A)(1+Ae^{-k(x-b)})^{-2}\frac{(Ae^{-2k(x-b)})}{(\frac{R+k}{k})(\frac {R+k}{k}+1)}+ \int.....\color{red}{\big]}    \tag{b}
$$

Comment: I don't see where 2.323 applies here, since the quantity multiplying $e^{-Rx}$ is not a polynomial.

Comment: @MarkFischler Thanks for pointing out that mistake. I tried integration by parts also given by equation b in question. Integration by parts is also not working.

Comment: Integration by parts in this case will not give more a polynomial than before, and the remark of Mark Fischler will be still valid.

Comment: @JeanMarie how do I solve the problem then? How do I get hypergeometric series?

Comment: I have asked Mathematica. It finds a solution with an Hypergeometric2F1 function only when $A=1/n$ with $n\in \mathbb{N}^*$. The expression it gives is different from yours and much much more complicated. Can you say why you are interested in obtaining a primitive function ?

Comment: x is finite. i want to integrate from 0 to x. this integral is part of solution of a differential equation. i have the boundary conditions for equation. Also, does this mean that result you obtained is applicable only for a very narrow range and that solution for this integral doea not exist practically?

Comment: The strange thing is that WA has given you a result. But it can make implicit assumptions... you did not intend to do. As I have asked Mathematica with a very proper syntax, and that it does not given any result in the general, i would say : yes, there is no explicit primitive when $A$ not the inverse of an integer. But you can take integrals nevertheless...